# (Oracle) How to get sum value inside loop?

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, sum

I need value of sum inside loop.

```
DECLARE
VAR_PCT NUMBER;
CURSOR C1 IS 
SELECT A, B FROM TBL;
BEGIN
FOR REC1 IN C1
  LOOP
--This where i need the value of sum(rec1.b) to calculate VAR_PCT:=(REC1.B/SUM(REC1.B))*100
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REC1.A ||'|'|| REC1.B ||'|'||VAR_PCT)
END LOOP;
END;
```

So, I basically need to figure out how to get the sum of B.

**EDIT:**

I forgot that I have one more variable that accumulate before the sum

```
*FOR REC1 IN C1
      LOOP*
    VAR_X := VAR_X+REC1.B
    *--This where i need the value of sum(rec1.b) to calculate VAR_PCT:=(REC1.B/SUM(REC1.B))*100
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REC1.A ||'|'|| REC1.B ||'|'||VAR_PCT)
    END LOOP;*
```

And the VAR_PCT is value for (VAR_X/SUM(REC1.B))*100

That's why I need calculate it inside the loop.

Comment: It is supposed to be fetched in the `SQL` itself, if otherwise, run the loop twice, first to calculate the `SUM`  and also store the resultset into a collection. Later, print the results traversing the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function `sum(col) over ()` to find the overall total in the cursor definition itself. This is usually more performant then doing thing procedurally in a loop.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR C1 IS 
        SELECT A, B, 100 * b / sum(b) over () VAR_PCT FROM TBL;
BEGIN
    FOR REC1 IN C1
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REC1.A ||'|'|| REC1.B ||'|'||REC1.VAR_PCT)
    END LOOP;
END;
```

If the sum is for each A, then use `partition by`:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR C1 IS 
        SELECT A, B, 100 * b / sum(b) over (partition by A) VAR_PCT FROM TBL;
BEGIN
    FOR REC1 IN C1
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REC1.A ||'|'|| REC1.B ||'|'||REC1.VAR_PCT)
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, but I forgot something. Please kindly review my edited question.

Comment: @sunudioh - I already calculated it in the SQL itself. See `100 * b / sum(b) over () VAR_PCT`

Comment: Oh Yes I understand now. The sum can be use as REC1.VAR_PCT inside the loop. Thanks a lot sir. You saved my day again.